# How to convert char to int in array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, console

How to change char value in array to int value? and detect first element and second element in array

```
arr = [a,a,a,b,b,a,b]
```

first element = a

second element = b

```
a = 1, b = 2
```

My expected output

```
arr = [1,1,1,2,2,1,2]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, can you please provide your attempts at solving this so far? That way you can see where you went wrong and outline specifically what you're having issues with. Can you also please clarify what the output should be if the input is `['x', 'y']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like so.

You can only get the char code of an index in a string. Since we have an char array we can alsways get the index of `0`.
The smallest charcode is of `A` which is 65. In this example I transform `a` to `A` which resolves to `65` then I remove 64 since `a` should be `1`. Consecutively `b` is mapped to `B` which is 65 and resolves to `2` since 64 is removed

```js
const arr = ['a','a','a','b','b','a','b']


const res = arr.map(char => char.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) - 64)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: what is the function of charCodeAt(0) - 64?

Comment: can this function return negative numbers?  like arr = [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1]

Comment: @VelosterRake No, that is why I added the toUpperCase(). Only 1 - 26 (as long as only a-z and A-Z are passed as values)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (I used NodeJs console):

```
> let a = ['a','a','a','b','b','a','b']
undefined
> a
[
  'a', 'a', 'a',
  'b', 'b', 'a',
  'b'
]
> var result = []
> for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
... result.push(a[i].charCodeAt(0))
... }
7
> result
[
  97, 97, 97, 98,
  98, 97, 98
]
```

> 

Comment: How to change 97 as 1 and 98 as 2?

Answer (score 0):

```
let a =1;
let b =2;
let  arr = [a,a,a,b,b,a,b]

arr = arr.map((x) => {
    return x.toString()
})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will not work as it does not convert the letters into numbers like the OP is asking for.